Open-source Google Keep alternatives?
Is there any comparable alternative to Google's Keep?
Features I require:

notes must support including images (via copy and paste) and other files (PDFs) and treat them as attachments/image gallery, not necessarily inline (because there may be many images/large images)
notes, images and PDFs must be indexed/searchable (via OCR (ie easyocr))

I wrote a note taking app with integrated live search (https://github.com/jjYBdx4IL/ajax-solnotes), but abandoned it because Google Keep does perfect OCR on images, which I can just copy and paste into notes there. I also don't really want to create a new fancy UI from scratch.
So what would you recommend to achieve the goal? Is there a universal UI framework that let's me build that without re-inventing the UI wheel? Or is there a complete and free solution already existing that I simply overlooked?

Check out Obsidian.
It is available for PC (Windows, Linux, Mac) and mobile platforms (Android, iOS).
All files are stored locally in Markdown format.
It has many plugins that extend its capabilities, including OCR.
